Насколько верно изобразил С. Я. Маршак идею Шекспира в сонете 16?

Считается, что сонеты 1 — 125 посвящены Прекрасному другу (точный адресат неизвестен), но при этом в них присутствует одна и та же идея.  Бытие  гл.1-26:  И благословил их Бог, говоря: плодитесь и размножайтесь...

Но так ли актуален был этот вопрос в Англии XVI века? Отнюдь нет, рождаемость была высокой, и это неудивительно. Эпидемии оспы и чумы  постоянно преследовали европейское население, и люди были заинтересованы в продолжении  своего рода. Это касалась как простых людей, так и аристократов, к которым, вероятно, принадлежал друг Шекспира.

Тогда зачем эту вполне понятную идею повторять 125 раз? Но именно так переводит сонеты Маршак, в том числе в сонете 16: Отдав себя, ты сохранишь навеки Себя в созданье новом — в человеке. Или там была другая идея?

В настоящее время дословный машинный перевод сонетов Шекспира не проблема для каждого читателя, и можно сверить тексты.  И вот в сонете 16 расхождение значительное, как и везде.  Но там присутствует еще интересный момент: английский бард  обращается к теме линий жизни, которые человек может исправить «своим милым искусством».


О чем идет речь?

Борьба с Шекспиром началась...  А какие претензии? Вопрос конкретный, анализ художественного текста  входит в школьную программу по русскому языку (даже не по литературе).  Орфографических и стилистических ошибок, думаю, нет.  Я активно работаю на форуме, практически каждый день отвечаю на несколько вопросов, в то время как многие только присутствуют. Можно же мне задать хотя бы один свой вопрос без минусовок, хотя бы в качестве бонуса.

А что, опять минус поставили?

Серж, так с того и начали, сначала два минуса проставили (за вопрос и за мой ответ).

На форуме опять 25. Прекратите флудить! Это форум русского языка, а клуб обмена мнениями о замысле автора. Прекратите захламлять обсуждения мусором. Минус вам и голос за закрытие вопроса

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он выходит за рамки тематики форума. Обсуждении истории, философии, литературы и субъективные оценки литературных произведений следует производить в другом месте

Это не флуд, а интересные вопросы для обсуждения. Не нравится — не отвечайте!

Серж, интересно то, то восприятие поэзии и любого художественного творчества всегда субъективно, но в школах анализ стихов начинается уже в младших классах. Литература важна для становления личности человека,  поэтому тема эта есть а ЕГЭ.  "Литературный аргумент - это, пожалуй, основной и обязательный критерий. Если ваш текст написан без опоры на литературное произведение, то "зачета" не видать, какие бы красивые слова и образы вы не подобрали". https://5uglov.ru/post/18101_3_dnya_do_itogovogo_sochineniya2023_formuliruem_argumenti

16.But wherefore do not you a mightier way
Make war upon this bloody tyrant Time,
And fortify yourself in your decay
With meanes more blessed than my barren rhyme?
Now stand you on the top of happy hours,
And many maiden gardens, yet unset,
With virtuous wish would bear your living flowers,
Much liker than your painted counterfeit:
So should the lines of life that life repair
Which this time's pencil or my pupil pen
Neither in inward worth nor outward fair
Can make you live yourself in eyes of men:
To give away yourself keeps yourself still,
And you must live drawn by your own sweet skill.
Но где ваш меч несущий стройный лад,
Сражающий времён кровавых Ритм,
И где щит ваш, граничащий распад,
Что краше всех моих бесплодных рифм?
Сейчас с вершин счастливый киньте взгляд,
Ведь множество нетронутых садов
В обёртке обесцвеченных оград
Ждут ваших оживающих цветов:
Живите так, чтоб жизнь лечила вас,
Чтоб шрам пропал и времени, и мой,
Сокрытый свет и честность напоказ,
Не будят в спящих людях взгляд живой:
Отдав себя, но сохраня собой,
Рисуйте жизни дар своей рукой.
Я думаю, основной смысл этого сонета в том, что ученик не должен слепо полагаться на учителя, и должен сразить не только время, но то, что осталось во времени, но уже бесплодно, так как отцвело, черпая вдохновение в жизни, а не цепляясь за прожитое.
18.Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
Thou art more lov'ly and more temperate:
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
And summer's lease hath all too short a date;
Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
And often is his gold complexion dimmed;
And every fair from fair sometime declines,
By chance or nature's changing course untrimmed:
But thy eternal summer shall not fade,
Nor lose possession of that fair thou ow'st,
Nor shall Death brag thou wand'rest in his shade*,
When in eternal lines to time thou grow'st.
So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.
Мне ль должно лета срок сравнить с тобой?
Твой дар искусный слаще и скромней,
Ветра порыв трясёт бутон драгой,
Растратит лето всё за майский день;
Да иногда льёт зной небесный глаз,
Но чаще лик златой его закрыт;
Так красота красе даёт отказ,
Случайно иль природа так велит:
Но твоё лето вечно будет цвесть,
Лишь не утрать красы, что жизнь даёт,
И не собьет с пути тенями Смерть,
Паки растёшь, бессмертье вновь взойдет,
И будет вечно длиться летний день,
Лишь не утрать красы, что жизнь даёт,
И не собьет с пути хвастливо Тень,
Паки живёшь бессмертие не умрёт.
Сколько вздымает грудь иль видит свет,
Столько живёт, давая жизнь тебе...
17.Who will believe my verse in time to come
Кто будет верить в мой стих, куплет в будущем?
If it were filled with your most high deserts?
Если он был наполнен вашими высокими заслугами(достоинствами)
Though yet, heaven knows, it is but as a tomb
Хотя пока, небеса знают, оно так, но как могила?
Which hides your life, and shows not half your parts.
Которая скроет вашу жизнь, и не покажет и половины частей(заслуг)
If I could write the beauty of your eyes,
Если я мог бы писать красоту ваших глаз
And in fresh numbers number all your graces,
И в свежих числах перечесть все ваши грации
The age to come would say, 'This poet lies;
Возраст придёт чтобы сказать: "Этот поэт лжёт"
Such heavenly touches ne'er touched earthly faces.'
Такие небесные касания никогда не коснутся земных лиц\
So should my papers (yellowed with their age)
Так должна ли моя бумага(пожелтевшая от её возраста)
Be scorned, like old men of less truth than tongue,
Быть презираемой, как старики менее правдивые, чем болтливые
And your true rights be termed a poet's rage
И ваше по праву, будет названо безумием поэта
And stretchd metre of an ntique song:
И растянутым слогом античной песни
But were some child of yours alive that time,
Но было бы живо дитя ваше в то время,
You should live twice, in it and in my rhyme.
Вы могли бы жить дважды, в том(нём) и в моей рифме
Кто будет верить в стих мой апосля?
Хоть с вас рисую лучшую картину,
Пока, о небо, так всё, но земля
Схоронит жизнь и чести половину.
Ах если б мог красу очей списать
И сумму граций в числах перечесть,
Пройдут года и скажут: лжёт опять;
Таких прекрасных черт не тронет смерть.
Ну что ж бумага стерпит, пожелтев
От желчи ртов болтающих старух,
Что ваш античный профиль располнел,
Поэт безумен, стих его протух:
Но если б жило ваше вдруг дитя,
Вы жили б дважды, в нём и у меня.
По-моему, получилось прекрасно! Издевательский стих с юмором, такой викторианский троллинг. Половина чести = получестный/ая, ай хорошо.
"Вы жили б дважды, в нём и у меня." - звучит очень двусмысленно, учитывая, что стих наполнен тонким троллингом.
19.Devouring Time, blunt thou the lion's paws,
пожирающее время, оглушит тебя львиной лапой,
Когда тигриной лапой оглушит
Когда когтистый лапой оглушит
О время, тигр нещадный что разит
And make the earth devour her own sweet brood;
И кровь впитает свежую земля
Плоть будет тигр жадно рвать, земля
И Время-тигр плоть рванёт, земля
Прожорливое Время, а земля
Заставит землю проглотить её собственную сладкую кровь
Pluck the keen teeth from the fierce tiger's jaws,
Впитает кровь и ...
Впитает кровь и тело иссушит,
And burn the long-lived phoenix in her blood;
Из крови феникс оживёт, горя.
Make glad and sorry seasons as thou fleet'st,
And do whate'er thou wilt, swift-footed Time,
To the wide world and all her fading sweets;
утех
But I forbid thee one most heinous crime:
Но запрещу один геенны грех
O, carve not with thy hours my love's fair brow,
о твоими часами не вырезай  моей любви честный взгляд
Nor draw no lines there with thine ntique pen;
ни рисунка ни линии там твоей античной кисти
Him in thy course untainted do allow
Ему в твоём течении неизменно делать позволь
For beauty's pattern to succeeding men.
Для повторения красоты в следующих людях
Yet, do thy worst, old Time: despite thy wrong,
My love shall in my verse ever live young.
Моя любовь будет в моём стихе всегда жить молодой.
Рази наотмашь, Хронос*, лапой льва,
Пусть кровь впитает сладкую земля
Своих детей; кромсай, кусай, бивай,
Из крови феникс** оживёт, горя.
Теки сквозь боль и радость, сквозь века,
Сквозь мир открытый, где не скрыть утех,
Как жизни быстротечная Река;
Лишь запрещу один геенны грех:
Не вырезай часов в моём челе,
Моей любви штрихами не состарь,
Пусть он живёт собой, навеселе,
Красой в грядущих людях прорастай.
Не вырезай морщин в моём челе,
Моей любви часами не состарь,
Пусть он собой живёт, навеселе,
Красой в грядущих людях прорастай.
Так будь жесток, но Век, пусть мой герой
Живёт в стихе любовью молодой.
Да, будь жесток, Старик, но мой герой
Стихом прибудет вечно молодой.
*devouring Time - пожирающее время, суть мифа о Хроносе.
**Феникс - переводчики видимо не шарили за лор, феникс - такой птиц, который воскресает, когда сгорают его останки.
А 3 строфу все переводчики подумали, что love's - это друг, и вышла какая-то чепуха, но нет, это не друг, а любовь, то есть Ш просит хранить не друга, а любовь которую передает и ему-другу и другим людям через стих, а не через того, кто стал прообразом стиха и живёт праздной жизнью и умрёт, как умирают люди. То есть это стихотворение вообще не про друга, а про обращение к Времени.
A woman's face with Nature's own hand painted
Hast thou, the master-mistress of my passion;
A woman's gentle heart, but not acquainted
With shifting change, as is false women's fashion;
An eye more bright than theirs, less false in rolling,
Gilding the object whereupon it gazeth;
A man in hue, all hues in his controlling,
Which steals men's eyes and women's souls amazeth.
And for a woman wert thou first created,
Τill Nature as she wrought thee fell a-doting,
And by addition me of thee defeated,
By adding one thing to my purpose nothing.
But since she pricked thee out for women's pleasure,
Mine be thy love and thy love's use their treasure.
Ты женственен и нежен от Природы,
Владыка чувств, страстей моих царица,
И в мягком сердце нет твоём породы
Фальшивой переменчивой девицы,
Что лишь края позолотит, касаясь;
В расцвете муж, все краски под контролем,
И все мужские взгляды похищаешь,
Вскрывая души женские паролем.
Для матери ты создан был в подарок,
Но вдруг, Природа пала, обожая,
И, прибавляя мой к тебе огарок,
Дала ту вещь, хоть предпочту ничто я.
Приколот ей теперь и жён услада,
Так возлюби меня, отдав им злато.
23.As an unperfect actor on the stage,
Who with his fear is put besides his part,
Or some fierce thing replete with too much rage,
Whose strength's abundance weakens his own heart;
So I, for fear of trust, forget to say
The perfect ceremony of love's rite,
And in mine own love's strength seem to decay,
O'ercharged with burden of mine own love's might:
O let my books be then the eloquence
And dumb presagers of my speaking breast,
Who plead for love, and look for recompense,
More than that tongue that more hath more expressed.
O learn to read what silent love hath writ:
To hear with eyes belongs to love's fine wit.
Растерян на подмостках как актёр,
Кто дарит страх, взамен своей игры,
Иль грубый и напыщенный позёр,
Чей грозен вид от сердца нищеты;
Так я, страшась признать, забуду слог
Свершённой церемонии любви,
И сильный дух, моей любви залог,
Падёт под грузом собственной вины:
Так пусть из книги шёпот покаянья,
Немой предвестник из моей груди,
Мольбу любви и меру воздаянья
Откроет, раз язык не уследит.
О чти, внимай, любви молчащей шрифт:
Сквозь слухи зри, что мудро говорит.
21.So is it not with me as with that Muse,
Stirred by a painted beauty to his verse,
Who heaven itself for ornament doth use,
And every fair with his fair doth rehearse,
Making a couplement of proud compare
With sun and moon, with earth and sea's rich gems,
With April's first-born flowers, and all things rare
That heaven's air in this huge rondure hems.
O let me, true in love, but truly write,
And then believe me, my love is as fair
As any mother's child, though not so bright
As those gold candles fixed in heaven's air:
Let them say more that like of hearsay well,
I will not praise that purpose not to sell.
Ужель со мной не так, как с музой той,
Что красотой полнит его стихи,
Он из небес плетёт ажурный крой,
Что б соблюсти все почести в чести.
Как комплимент из гордости сорвёт
Апрельский самый первый первоцвет,
Всех лун и звезд, морей и стран щедрот,
Надует в пышных юбок этикет.
Позволь мне, про любовь, писать слова,
И верь, за тем моя любовь чиста
Как взор младенца, но не так светла,
Как светоч золотой на небесах.
Пускай молвы струится благодать,
Я без гроша, нет цели не продавать.
Пускай молвы струится благодать,
Раз без гроша, то цель не продавать.
22.My glass shall not persuade me I am old,
So long as youth and thou are of one date,
But when in thee time's furrows I behold,
Then look I death my days should expiate:
For all that beauty that doth cover thee
Is but the seemly raiment of my heart,
Which in thy breast doth live, as thine in me
How can I then be elder than thou art?
O therefore, love, be of thyself so wary
As I not for myself but for thee will,
Bearing thy heart, which I will keep so chary
As tender nurse her babe from faring ill:
Presume not on thy heart when mine is slain;
Thou gav'st me thine, not to give back again.
Напомню:
Не вырезай часов в моём челе,
Любви моей часами не состарь...
Стекло её, хотя внутри ты сам,
Огнём её весны пока храним,
Но через эти стёкла по часам,
Стекает время золотом морщин...
Моё стекло, не убедит, ведь я, старик,
Ты юн пока, ты не считаешь дни,
А время за бороздки убежит,
Раз видишь их, я смерть, за дни плати;
Как время по минуткам убежит,
Раз слышишь их, я смерть, за них плати:
Всё, чем прекрасен, чем пока прикрыт,
Лишь одеянье сердца моего,
В груди живу, твой клад во мне стучит,
Так как мне быть тогда, старей него?
В груди живу, мой дар в тебе горит,
Так как мне быть тогда, старей него?
О отчего, любовь, ты приуныл,
Не для себя я, волен ты желать,
Носитель сердца ты, а я хранил,
Как то дитя, что пеленала мать,
Носитель сердца, буду я хранить,
Тебя, дитя, что пеленала мать:
И не серчай, раз я сражён, забудь;
Тебя, что ты отдал мне, не вернуть.
И не серчай, что ты сражён, забудь;
Тебя, раз ты отдал, уж не вернуть.
Я понял, о чём 20, доделал.
13.O that you were your self, but love you are
No longer yours than you yourself here live;
Against this coming end you should prepare,
And your sweet semblance to some other give:
So should that beauty which you hold in lease
Find no determination; then you were
Your self again after yourself's decease,
When your sweet issue your sweet form should bear.
Who lets so fair a house fall to decay,
Which husbandry in honour might uphold
Against the stormy gusts of winter's day
And barren rage of death's eternal cold?
O, none but unthrifts: dear my love, you know
You had a father, let your son say so.
О были вы собой, но вы любовь
Уж более не ваши, если живы;
Раз правы, то продолжите со слов,
Тех сладких, в других, когда от края защитимы:
Вы красотой одарены в залог*,
Её не разделяя; но тогда
В другом её найдете, если срок,
Ваш сладкий, уже вышел навсегда.
Тогда в другом найдете, если сок,
Ваш сладкий, уже вышел навсегда.
Кто безразлично разорит свой дом,
Где мужества и славы был оплот,
И пустит внутрь ветреный садом
Зимы и смерти, вечный хоровод?
О, полно тратить: смилуйтесь, вот знак,
Был ваш отец и сын ваш скажет так;
О, полно спорить: смилуйтесь, вот знак,
Что правы вы, пусть дальше, было так.
Соннет не давался, и потому не нравился. Казалось не Ш, а какой-то невнятный плагиат. Но это просто значит, что нужно перевести лучше, чем кажется. И вот... теперь он мне нравится: введена тема правоты, разделения-определения-различия, сохранена неопределённость пола: к кому обращение, к юноше или девушке? Я доволен.
*кстати отсылка к 4 соннету, "природой обделён, тогда займи, она подаст и ещё даром"
Решил поправить в конце, father от  fader - исчезающий, тот кто был.
И кстати, вот вам и смысловое среднее, то что между отцом и сыном.
Mine eye hath played the painter and hath stelled
Thy beauty's form in table of my heart;
My body is the frame wherein 'tis held,
And prspective it is best painter's art.
For through the painter must you see his skill
To find where your true image pictured lies,
Which in my bosom's shop is hanging still,
That hath his windows glazd with thine eyes.
Now see what good turns eyes for eyes have done:
Mine eyes have drawn thy shape, and thine for me
Are windows to my breast, wherethrough the sun
Delights to peep, to gaze therein on thee.
Yet eyes this cunning want to grace their art,
They draw but what they see, know not the heart.
В глазу звезда, когда прекрасный бюст,
Рисую твой у сердца на станке,
Предвижу тело сдюжит звёздный груз,
Моей работы лучшей на земле.
Сквозь глаз художник кажет естество,
И различит во лжи ваш правды лик,
И сохнет он уж в сердца мастерской,
Тот в чей хрустальный глаз свет не проник.
Теперь гляжу глаза в глаза, готов:
Мой глаз всеотразил твои черты,
И первый вздох в открытое окно
Для солнца, чей восторг глядит чрез ты.
И каждый вдох открытое окно
И солнца, чей восторг глядит на ты.
Глаза умело прячут в свой ларец,
Всё милое, не зная, кто творец.
Глаза украдкой прячут в свой ларец,
Не видя сердца истинный творец.
He+art - вот оно как...
Творец, кстати, - ты+варить, варить=art.
И говорил, что он будет делать человека.
25.Let those who are in favour with their stars
Of public honour and proud titles boast,
Whilst I, whom fortune of such triumph bars,
Unlooked for joy in that I honour most.
Great princes' favourites their fair leaves spread
But as the marigold at the sun's eye,
And in themselves their pride lies buried,
For at a frown they in their glory die.
The painful warrior famousd for fight,
After a thousand victories once foiled,
Is from the book of honour rased quite,
And all the rest forgot for which he toiled:
Then happy I that love and am belovd
Where I may not remove, nor be removd.
Пусть те, кто в свете звёзд был порождён,
Гордятся, от кичливости манер,
Но я, по счастью славы ограждён,
Не рад, пускай, но славен не в пример.
Любимцы славных в славе их живя,
Как златоцветы тешат солнц венец,
Но в гордости их славу погребя,
Нахмурятся, когда придёт конец.
О горе воин знаменит боях,
Из тысячи побед отдал одну,
И стёрт из книг о славных временах
И всеми позабыт не по труду:
В той счастлив я любви и в той влюблён,
Где не возвышен и не удалён.
Но в гордости(,) их(,) славу погребя, - как же мне нравятся эти предложения "казнить нельзя помиловать")
26.Lord of my love, to whom in vassalage
Thy merit hath my duty strongly knit,
To thee I send this written ambassage
To witness duty, not to show my wit;
Duty so great, which wit so poor as mine
May make seem bare, in wanting words to show it,
But that I hope some good conceit of thine
In thy soul's thought (all naked) will bestow it,
Till whatsoever star that guides my moving
Points on me graciously with fair aspect,
And puts apparel on my tottered loving,
To show me worthy of thy sweet respect:
Then may I dare to boast how I do love thee,
Till then, not show my head where thou mayst prove me.
Любви мой князь, тот для кого служу,
Твоих заслуг и мой привязан долг,
Письмо к тебе сие за тем пишу,
Не ради шуток откровенный слог;
Так долг велик, что ум беднятский мой
Весь обнажён, нуждаясь рассказать,
Но ты так щедр душевной наготой,
Что и без слов способен всё узнать.
Пусть луч звезды любой моё движенье
Направит благосклонно в лучший вид,
И даст тебе узреть преображение
Той робкой, неуверенной любви:
Опять дерзну схвастнуть, люблю тебя я,
Ну а пока, узнай не узнавая.
27.Weary with toil, I haste me to my bed,
The dear repose for limbs with travel tired,
But then begins a journey in my head,
To work my mind, when body's work's expired;
For then my thoughts (from far where I abide)
Intend a zealous pilgrimage to thee,
And keep my drooping eyelids open wide,
Looking on darkness which the blind do see;
Save that my soul's imaginary sight
Presents thy shadow to my sightless view,
Which, like a jewel (hung in ghastly night),
Makes black night beauteous, and her old face new.
Lo thus by day my limbs, by night my mind,
For thee, and for myself, no quiet find.
Устав в труде, спешу в мою кровать,
Ищу покой, окончив долгий путь,
Но к цели вновь стремится голова,
Труд разума, лишь телом отдохнуть.
Лишь я и мысль (как долго я терплю)
В желаньи истом сблизиться с тобой,
И ставни век закрытых распахну,
Смотрю во тьму так, как глядит слепой ;
Воображу дары в твоей тени,
Их схороню в глазах, раз не глядят,
Как жемчуга (парящие в ночи)
Лик ночи дряхлой, крася, молодят.
Раз кончен день, ночь на уме опять,
Тебе и мне покой не отыскать.
28.How can I then return in happy plight
That am debarred the benefit of rest?
When day's oppression is not eased by night,
But day by night and night by day oppressed;
And each (though enemies to either's reigne)
Do in consent shake hands to torture me,
The one by toil, the other to complain
How far I toil, still farther off from thee.
I tell the day to please him thou art bright,
And dost him grace when clouds do blot the heaven;
So flatter I the swart-complexioned night,
When sparkling stars twire not thou gild'st the even:
But day doth daily draw my sorrows longer,
And night doth nightly make griefs' strength seem stronger.
Как в счастии могу вернуть я печаль,
Раз отстранён я обрясти покой?
Чтоб день в ночи легко не утопал,
Но ночь на день, и день сменял другой;
И каждый (хоть не всякий был врагом)
Подельник, и терзатель для меня,
Один трудом своим, другой кнутом
Слов про труд мой, я сторонюсь тебя.
Я день прошу твой блеск изобразить,
Пусть будет благ, хотя б с небес ведро,
Мне лестью смоль ночи не исказить,
Раз танцем звёзд ты золотишь её:
Но день за днём пусть длятся мне печали,
Чтоб ночь за ночью горе продолжали.
29.When in disgrace with Fortune and men's eyes,
I all alone beweep my outcast state,
And trouble deaf heaven with my bootless cries,
And look upon myself and curse my fate,
Wishing me like to one more rich in hope,
Featured like him, like him with friends possessed,
Desiring this man's art and that man's scope,
With what I most enjoy contented least;
Yet in these thoughts myself almost despising,
Haply I think on thee, and then my state
Like to the lark at break of day arising
From sullen earth sings hymns at heaven's gate;
For thy sweet love rememb'red such wealth brings
That then I scorn to change my state with kings.
Когда гоним порядком и судьбой,
В немилости, чужой среди людей,
Тревожит высь глухую плач босой,
Кляну жеребий мой и свой удел,
Желаю хоть каких урвать надежд,
Его иметь привязанностей круг,
Хочу талант того, и тех одежд,
Лишь этой мыслью тешу свой досуг;
Во всём меня те мысли унижают,
Вдруг вспомню, о тебе, и снова лад,
Как жаворонка трель с земли* встречает
рассвет, взмывая до небесных врат;
Припомню благодать любви твоей,
Удел мой слаще доли королей.
*Жаворонки на рассвете и закате поют сидя на земле.
31.Thy bosom is endeard with all hearts,
Which  I by lacking have supposd dead,
And there reigns love and all love's loving parts,
And all those friends which I thought buried.
Hath dear religious love stol'n from mine eye,
As interest of the dead, which now appear,
But things remov'd that hidden in thee lie.
Thou art the grave where buried love doth live,
Hung with the trophies of my lovers gone,
Who all their parts of me to thee did give;
That due of many now is thine alone.
Their images I loved I view in thee,
And thou (all they) hast all the all of me
Твоя утроба всех творцов вместила,
Хоть почитал ушедших я мертвей,
И в ней царит любовь, и всё, что мило,
С чем хоронил и помню я друзей.
Как много слёз терзаний укатилось
Из глаз, ужели, вера убежит
За смерти интерес, что вдруг явилась,
Нет, все в тебе, что отдано, лежит.
Ты склеп создал, где чувства охранил,
Украсив даром прожитой любви,
Кто части их, меня, тебе дарил,
Тех многих дань, в одном тебе, внутри.
Их образ милый вижу я в тебе,
И ты (они все) есть теперь во мне.

Спасибо за перевод! Я не совсем еще поняла смысл третьей строфы и концовки, но надеюсь понять.   Сонеты связаны одной темой,  но вряд ли ее можно обозначить словами.  Но вот у Маршака это как будто ясно обозначено,  и это  "поучение" мне не по душе.  Я читала про другое прочтение Шекспира, где переводчик хочет изобразить одни чувства, но это другая крайность.  Что вы об этом думаете?  Хотела написать более подробный отзыв, но коротко не получается)  Может, в письме напишу, но только если вы позволите.

Не видела я вашего дополнения, интересная мысль, надо вникнуть)  Вы считаете, что там отношения ученика и учителя?  Эмоционально не могу это воспринять и понять, чего-то не хватает.  Но я тот еще ценитель)  А вы скорее правы)   Меня интересует гарантированное "бессмертие", пусть расскажет секрет.  Это шутка, но всё же...

Загадка слов:  Neither in inward worth nor outward fair.  Ни по внутренней ценности, ни по внешней справедливости.  // you live yourself in eyes of men. Ты живешь  в глазах людей.

Что-то вроде "ни ценность и ни воздаяние", что-то, что не нужно ни беречь, ни гордиться. Но это хоть ещё строфу сочиняй) Подумаю ещё)

@Sharon кажется стало лучше.

Да, теперь красиво)  Правильность стиха, как и всего остального,  начинается с красоты формы)  Теперь у меня как обычно: полного понимания смысла нет, но оно как раз не нужно, чтобы осталась многозначность и объемность текста.  Надо еще прислушаться к форме, чтобы принять сонет в любимые)  Пока у меня их всего пять.  А песенку никак нельзя?

Спасибо за перевод сонета 18, мне он тоже интересен)  Пыталась сама его перевести, но по Шекспиру не очень получается, все больше по Маршаку)

@Sharon Пожалуйста) песни пока тренирую, но должны быть.  На почту пишите, конечно, она у вас есть)

Спасибо,  боюсь помешать вашему творчеству, но напишу если будет  что. Но вот давно хотела вас попросить, вы не могли бы переписать сонет 12. Он мне очень нравится, но хотелось бы его услышать в  таком же стиле, как 5, 14, 15. Пжста, при возможности)

@Sharon стиль, вы имеете ввиду музыкальный, чтобы музыка была другая? Просто стих не расслабляющий, а суровый) "Умри, пока млад кто тебе так мил", "храни в потомках храбрость до конца"...
Как вы думаете, почему Ш перешёл в стихе 16 на ВЫ?

Скорее не музыка, а звучание голоса. особенно в первой части. Я вообще первые сонеты Шекспира слышу как элегии.  В них  и щемящая грусть о кратковременности всего цветущего на земле, и понимание необходимости такого хода жизни. И даже третья строфа And die as fast as they see others grow звучит не как призыв, а как вывод, как вариант решения.  Для сравнения в сонете 16 больше ораторского искусства, наподобие  Демосфена: Так когда же, когда наконец, граждане афинские, вы будете делать, что нужно? Чего вы дожидаетесь?) Может быть,  поэтому здесь обращение на ВЫ.

@Sharon элегия - это 18.

А сонет 12 что?  В первой части описание природы, а дальше  задушевное обращение к другу.  Шекспир в первых сонетах вообще очень лиричен и задумчив,  будто делится с нами впечатлениями, но вот в сонете 16 призывает к активному противостоянию времени. Это я не знаю, как будет звучать)

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/lWFCBi6oybWNgQ - 16

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/jjwrpTHgN-OBSw -18. Пока с ошибками, но потом исправлюсь)

Спасибо! Очень похоже на настоящий театр! Послушаю еще и потом напишу вам на почту о впечатлении)  // Хотелось бы  услышать отзывы наших участников (основная мысль стиха и ее художественное воплощение).  Материала  приведено достаточно,  а мнение читателей всегда важно автору.

О сонете 17.  А где же медоточивый и сладкоречивый мистер Шекспир, которого так любили студенты Кембриджа? Прощай, элегия? Вообще говоря, в периодизации сонетов пора навести порядок. Шекспир вовсе не готовил сонеты к публикации,  а это важно учитывать.  Цикл 1— 26  называется воспевание друга. Ничего себе, воспевание!  // А троллинг  здесь — это что-то вроде дразнилки, да? Но почему он викторианский?  Английское общество 16 века вроде бы викторианским не назовешь, а каким?

Но стих мне нравится, троллинг так троллинг. Это такой веселый троллинг. // А  что значит чести половина,  дважды воспеть?  Прикол такой?  Хвалить наполовину и так же воспевать?  Полувоспетый, но не истинно воспетый. На настоящее прославление достоинств не хватило? // Пожелание. Мне кажется, в концовке рифма должна быть точная, для большей убедительности.

@Sharon я понимаю так: почему на "вы"? этот сонет обращёние к даме, то есть Ш заказали стих, который бы воспевал прелести дамы, и строфу он начинает с шаблонных "у вас не счесть граций и достоинств, небеса подтвердят, ваши глаза прекрасны", но заканчивает противоположным "а земля(гробница) схоронит вашу жизнь, но и почти все ваши заслуги(в оригинале)".
То есть он как бы тонко, но хамит, уклоняясь от шаблонной оды-воспевания красоты.

При этом выставляя себя тоже жертвой такой ситуации, что его обвинят в безумии за то, что он будет писать воспевание данной даме(ну может быть юноше, что вряд ли, мне кажется). И получается не посвящение, а скорее изобличение несовершенств. Ну и заканчивается всё фразой "вы жили б дважды, в нём(в ребёнке)... и у меня", при том что у него она воспет критически, а не восторженно, и это добавляет каламбура. Но не прикопаться, потому что всё логично... Думаю насчет строчки про античный профиль располнел..., а в остальном мне нравится. Но потом ещё мб переделаю, потому что настроение захватывает.

То есть Ш ни разу не назидателен и не поучителен, как его преподносят, выше же есть соннет про проповедь, где он говорит "каждый всё же был бы рад, знать как избечь пути и в этот ад". Ш уходит от назидательности в парадоксальность(противоречивость и двойственность) и игру образов и слов. Это основная фишка.

"античный профиль располнел"  вполне на месте. Но вы, мy dear poet, совсем отбились от стада))  Все переводчики сонета 17 твердят одно и то же и двойственности не видят) Вам придется в дополнение  к переводам написать маленькую энциклопедию по Шекспиру)    Вот мои любимые сонеты 5, 7, 12, 14, 15, в чем там двойственность? Мне там Шекспир кажется вполне искренним.   Хотела бы я услышать в вашем переводе сонет 74. У меня там к переводу Маршака вопросов нет, мне он очень нравится, но вы, наверное, найдете)

@Sharon 5 весь на двойственности построен: "то что в границах, то чисто, но теряет красоту/а то что за границей, то не красота", живое-безгранично, а смерть закрыта в границах, но чиста(честна). 7 - солнце молодое восходит, но потом надлом и раздвоение(парабола) рождающее новый день. Солнце движется по параболе, зенит - и точка высшего величия и точка надлома.

Двойственность да, но не двусмысленность, как в сонете 17.  У Шекспира и построение стиха везде двухчастное.

@Sharon двусмысленность это подтип этой двойственности, но двойственность даёт некий пафос, а двусмысленность даёт иронию и юмор. "Уж сок остыл и стар бесстрастный пень, ни красоты ни памяти её" - типичная шутка Ш.По сути очень похожая на то, чем наполнен 17 соннет.

Ну нет! Там метафора, совсем не шутка.  И кому же писал Ш. такие сонеты, как 17?  Или он только студентам это читал?

To change your day of youth to sullied night - ты растёшь к звёздам, но в спорах со временем меняешь день на загрязнённую (светлыми пятнашками) ночь. Я думаю, 17 соннет - это ответ, когда его попросили написать посвящение какой-то даме, он вместо того, чтобы пойти по общепринятым шаблонам, сделал вот так.

А что? Художественный прием, антитеза.  // Смелый поступок для актера театра)

Нет, я думаю, он читал 17 соннет публично, он же смешной. Это же игра слов и понятий, обман ожиданий. Писать по шаблонам - это притворство по сути, но за денежку этим занимались поэты, и все это понимали. Но чтобы ловко сказать правду матку, так не многие могли. Одновременно отвешивая вроде бы посылки комплиментарности даме и одновременно переводя разговор в совершенно иное русло.

Он у вас вроде шута, которому все позволено) Эти персонажи особенно умны и ироничны, короли их любили.  // Но дело в том, что Ш.  вне театра  вообще  не существовал, только там обычной публике было дозволено его видеть.  Не осталось никаких воспоминаний о нем.

Он у вас вроде шута,  - шут один из ключевых персонажей трагедий, а значит и часть многогранного Ш. Но да, этот стих близок к шутовству, но тем не менее тонок. Хотя, может быть, я убрал из него лирические моменты. Но другие переводчики напрочь выхолостили шутовство из переводов, и поэтому получилось сухое назидание, ушла ирония.

Если бы Ш. готовил сам сонеты к изданию, он включил бы туда сонет 17? Может, это вообще черновой набросок к какой-нибудь пьесе? Меня вообще удивляет нелогичность в расположении сонетов.

Ну соннет - это полноценное произведение, так что не думаю, что это прямо набросок, но мысли могут пересекаться перетекать в пьесы: но если ты живешь без мысли быть, умри один и дай тебя забыть... Насчёт публикаций я не знаю, ничего не могу сказать, кто и зачем публиковал это, могу только представить ситуацию и образ того, кто мог бы это придумать. Меня не так волнует передать некий смысл, мне интереснее кто это говорил. Хотя смысл тоже весьма интересен. Но исхожу я не из смысла внутри, а из ситуации и того, кто это мог написать и для кого.

Ну и шут вполне годиться как альтер-Эго, это нисколько не преуменьшает значимость артиста. Клоуны, шуты, мимы - это может быть очень лирично, но с юмором. Никулин, Марсель Марсо, но Ш более многогранен, он и Шут, он и Гамлен, он и Король, он и влюблённый Отелло или Ромео... У Ш много масок, но сам он под всеми этими масками остаётся самим собой-тобой, так что ли, стремится к этому.

Вам интересен тот, кто говорил, и его ситуация? В смысле вы реконструируете личность поэта так, как  представляете это по его стихам? Речь не идет о реальной жизни Ш, про которую мало что известно.   Это любопытно)  Множество масок и свое лицо тоже в маске.

@Sharon - личность, это не только факты. Личность, это ход мышления. Вот есть фраза: Though yet, heaven knows, it is but as a tomb - явно издевательская. Ты так красива,/ но лишь пока,/ хотя небо подтверждает, это так,/ но вот... могила... Ну для меня тут шутка очевидна. То есть этот человек умеет шутить. А найдите хоть одну шутку в переводах Маршака. Причем у Ш серьезное превращается в шутку, а шутка в серьзеное.

В сонете 74 есть.  Или он дословно переводит шутки Ш.

Какая? строчку.

Когда меня отправят под арест
Без выкупа, залога и отсрочки...  // А шут позволял себе многое, наверняка охранная грамота была.  Хотя в театре все можно.

Когда меня отправят под арест Без выкупа, залога и отсрочки...  - и о чём эта фраза, я думал вы хотите привести пример шутки у Маршака?

Просто Маршак обычно не очень последовательно  следует авторской лексике, а здесь он не только использовал "залог", но даже расширил тему. Такие ироничные метафоры не очень характерны дл него.

@Sharon 'Такие ироничные метафоры не очень характерны дл него.' - вы про Маршака? А я по то, что у Ш много иронии и юмора в стихах, который переводы не отражают. Нас таки опять закрыли, без повода, залога и отсрочки)

Закрыли... Придется запятые в сонетах Шекспира обсуждать) // Сонет 74 представляется мне "шутовским" по своей сути (что нехарактерно для переводов Маршака). Какой-то в нем особенный тон, бравада, насмешка по отношению к вечности, стремящейся поглотить любую жизнь.

@Sharon мне кажется, что это дело не в Ш, Ш тригикомичен, он леричен и в тоже время умудряется шутить, а не просто жаловаться. То есть вот 66 сонет: "And maiden virtue rudely strumpeted," - её все переводят а-ля "девственность вгоняется в разврат/девственность, поруганная груба". Но у Ш не такая конструкция фразы, у него начинается как бы одним манером, а потом происходит разворот смысла. Если сказать "А делает Б"  - этого не достаточно, тогда нет разворота это просто утверждение без поворота смысла. Поэтому я перевожу вроде "А такое, но вот так Б" - "И девой нежной/предан грубо был"

Фраза дробится на два сегмента и происходит конфликт внутри самой фразы. В этом ирония. Фраза есть, но внутри смыслы конфликтуют. "And right perfection/wrongfully disgraced," - слово perfection к чему относится? к праву-правильности - rights или к wrongfully? Грамматическая путаница. Если перфекшн это правильно, то одно, а если совершенна в несовершенстве, то другое. Я когда переводил об этом не думал, но сейчас могу это проанализировать. Поэтому мне хочется писать: славы злато/мутно от стыда. То есть происходит подъём и потом спад. А не вот так: "И неуместной почести позор,"

И почестей неправых омерзенье, - или вот так, хотя у Фенкеля немного лучше, но тоже не достаточно, потому что А не определено через восходящее настроение, хотя в целом А позитивно. То есть дело даже не в точности слов, а в этих переходах внутри фраз: "и правда, если прав любой дурак"- "соглашусь/правильно, что прав любой дурак", то есть согласие с тем, с чем не хочешь соглашаться. Вот такие моменты мне кажется это стиль Ш - дробление фразы в строке на два сегмента которые запутываются и конфликтуют. А не просто назидательное изобличение какого-то порока - "И прямоту, что глупостью слывет,'

То есть, не нужно в тупую делать утверждение "А - это Б", а надо подводить читателя к вопросу, а не давать ответ, как я уже писал до этого. Сначала описание, а ответ читатель найдет сам, а если не найдет, то всё было зря). Утверждение же, будет или пустой бравадой или ещё чем-то во что "не верю". Суть в том, чтобы создать материал для сотворчества, в не дать ответ такой, какой уже знает каждый. Как-то так мне это видится, и этого я не нахожу в переводах, но нахожу у Ш, а если не нахожу, предполагаю, что понял что-то неверно и стараюсь создать что-то подобное сам.

Спасибо!  Всё очень интересно! Уникальный материал для людей, занимающихся переводами вообще и Шекспира в частности.  Ну и для читателей, любящих английского поэта и поэзию в целом. Да и всем любителям русского языка  это должно быть интересно — я  воспринимаю такие обсуждения как воспитание художественного вкуса,  которое наконец вижу в деталях. //  Сонет 66 был один из немногих, который я знала у Шекспира, и он мне очень нравился. Я видела здесь поэта-публициста, очень убедительно бичующего недостатки общества. Самого поэта представляла очень туманно.

Ваш перевод полностью заслонил вариант Маршака — передо мной был реальный человек с его чувствами, мыслями, переживаниями; можно было представить ситуации, которые вызвали эти чувства.  Шекспир вообще тайна тайн, и увидеть его будто вживую — это редкая возможность. Образы и мысли, которые едва проглядывали в переводе Маршака,  приобрели действительно художественную  форму. Но все это более поздний анализ, а тогда  просто узнавание и восхищение.  И теперь я знаю еще и некоторые секреты таких переводов)

@Sharon да, Маршак часто слабоват), это мне нравится, 19 - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/QnaDFKPQSz2x8Q

Спасибо. Классно!  Скоро я с вашей подачи полюблю театр)

@Sharon в общем, я не совсем верно перевёл 19 первую строфу, хотя мне так нравится больше, но подумаю как исправить. 20 пока не знаю переводить, он меня смущает, хотя он сложный, много времени потратил, так и не придумал ничего нового) Вечером постараюсь ответить.

Да, 20 – это известный стих. Многие из него делают вывод о симпатиях поэта в его реальной жизни. Я как раз сейчас читаю материалы на тему философии в сонетах. Существует мнение, что многое там  символично и зашифровано, предназначалось для узкого круга знатоков поэзии. «Художественная форма  требовала эрудиции и подразумевала у читателей осведомленность в тонкостях стихотворства, эффекты которого были тщательно рассчитаны. Нужно было знать мифологию, устойчивые поэтические символы, трактовку разных тем другими поэтами, без чего ни идея, ни поэтические достоинства произведения не были ясными».

Своего рода тайнопись. Может, и так, но не знаю, насколько это верно. В то же время понимали его поэзию немногие образованные люди, вероятно его круга, а также студенчество, а потом все было быстро забыто. // Может, надо видеть связь между сонетами, какие-то общие приемы, как при разгадке неизвестного языка)

«Венера и Адонис» первое произведение Шекспира. «Венера домогается любви Адониса. Ее увещевания о продолжении рода, обращенные к юноше, как две капли воды напоминают увещевания героя сонетов к белокурому другу. Доводы ее красноречивы и убедительны, и Адонис уже готов сдаться. И все же разум в нем побеждает, и юноше удается устоять под натиском чувств».  Адонис погибает  на охоте   от клыков вепря, так и не продолжив свой род. Но жизнь Адониса продлевается иным образом – на его крови вырастает красно-белый цветок.  . Может,  в поэме можно найти ключ к пониманию этого цикла сонетов.

"Пусть другие хвалят Спенсера ц Чосера, я же буду поклоняться сладостному
мистеру Шекспиру и, чтобы почтить его, буду класть "Венеру и Адониса" под
свою подушку..."  (из студенческой  пьесы 1599 года). У некоторых
кембриджских студентов и преподавателей Шекспир буквально не сходил с языка.

@Sharon очень любопытно, действительно перекликается сильно. Но я не вижу в первых соннетах этого увещевания, вижу как раз второе. Но обставленного так, чтобы было двояко, несколько двояко, продолжение - да, способ - иной. Соннет 20 видится мне таковым. Несколько иначе, но похожие идеи. И там как раз принижается что ли роль женщины, не обесценивается, но говорится что да, но с ними лишь развлечение. А такой, чтобы детей рожай я пока нашёл только 13 соннет, и там обращение ВЫ и вероятно к даме, а не к юноше.

@Sharon "Две первые строчки неясны. Они могут означать либо «Единственному вдохновителю (следующие сонеты) Mr. W.H. все счастье» и т. д.; следовательно, «Mr. W.H.» – друг, которому адресовано большинство сонетов; либо «Единственному подателю  (следующих сонетов) Mr. W.H. все счастье» и т. д.; значит, «Mr. W.H.» – тот, кто снабдил текстами книготорговца для публикации. Если двузначность умышленная и представляет игру слов, возможно «Mr. W.H.» обозначает одновременно и друга, и подателя текстов." Ну вот в этом весь Ш, его нельзя воспринимать прямо, что ли. Он как бы серьезен, но при этом шутит.

И вот этой иронии и нет у переводчиков, в этом проблема. Они перевели все слишком линейно. Статья отличная.

Просто восторг!  Я едва узнала сонет 21, он прозвучал так современно,  так чувствуют люди во все времена.  Живая волна эмоций, Маршак отдыхает, и все остальные вместе с ним.  Хочется поздравить вас с этим прекрасным переводом.

@Sharon ага), я думаю все отдыхают в 21) и точность перевода 99%, есть конечно фраза несогласованная, но она мне нравится такой кривой, в 7 строфе) и это вы ещё не слышали исполнение... я тоже очень доволен 21 и неуверенный 23 ещё более уверенно звучит с ним в паре. и в 21 финальную фразу про свечи которые держат небеса никто не перевёл, даже чайковский неточен, хотя казалось бы, простая фраза, но какая эффектная...ну и про юбку музы)

Ну и сразу видно, что это ни про какого не друга, а про цикл о Чёрной даме)

И там такой вкуснейший ритмический переход в 3 строфе, я не понимаю, как вообще можно такое упускать. ХОТИТЕ УСЛЫШАТЬ ИДЕАЛЬНОЕ ЗВУЧАНИЕ СОННЕТА?)

Да, в первой части у вас просто фантастические образы, очень смелые и неожиданные.  От них головокружение, особенно при первом прочтении)  И там точные рифмы, которые мне всегда нравятся.  А исполнение будет?)  Да еще идеальное?!))  Как не хотеть!

Спасибо, очень впечатляюще! Идеальное звучание — это от слова идея, да?) Сначала о сонетах 17 и 23.  Сначала все было немного неожиданно,  но потом начался настоящий театр, где слушаешь, смеешься, удивляешься. Да, это чисто театральные вещицы, рассчитанные на игру актера, а не на простое прочтение . Тогда даже текст лучше понимаешь и соглашаешься с ним, хотя раньше хотелось что-то исправиться.  Но вот сонет 21 на любителя, мне не очень понятна композиция и стиль, просто не понимаю некоторых приемов.

С другой стороны, я  вообще люблю  всё «нежно-лимонадное или проникновенно-задумчивое», но понимаю, что художник должен искать новые формы)  Поэтому моя общая оценка — талантливо,  интересно!  Современный такой театр! И мои аплодисменты вам как актеру. Голосовые возможности у вас просто удивительные)

@Sharon щас отшлифую), просто первоначально многовато экспрессии, нужно меньше, и я переделал строчку, сделал мягче)

Ну да, переходы нужны,  но их нужно как-то рассчитывать по экспрессии. Они  основа композиции,  в них и заключено действие. И еще просьба – иногда голос плохо слышно и приходится напрягать слух, когда  вы переходите к лирике.

@Sharon новую ссылку даю на 21, сделал мягче, не кактят высоцкий и рычалки) на да ладно, я смирюсь:  17- https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Sg7Y8TkXYYtB2A  21 - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/6lzPNAnfsg1eng  23 - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/6KK4n5XZcsRb0Q

Да, теперь всё чудесно, я бы только из сонета 21 убрала бы переход и концовку.  Я ее, наверное, не понимаю, поэтому мне она мешает. Но это на ваше усмотрение. // Набрала в Яндексе "Театральность в сонетах Шекспира", но ничего не дали.  Есть "Сонетные отголоски в драматургии У. Шекспира", есть тема театра в некоторых сонетах.  И это все. Такое впечатление, что эта мысль никому  даже в голову не приходила?

@Sharon кстати, я 10 и 11 переделал тоже, не помню, присылал или нет? убрал высоцкого) сделал мягко, получилось намного лучше. Ну наверное не приходило из наших, там мб разбирали, но у нас чисто плодитесь и размножайтесь). Вы у Финкеля читали 21 соннет? Там вообще рофл как он убрал про свечи и небо, и Маршак тоже убрал)

@Sharon "Правдив в любви, правдив и в песне я:
Не как златые светочи в эфире,
Блистает красотой любовь моя,
А как любой рожденный в этом мире." - третья строфа) 21 Финкель.

Надо посмотреть. Я эти сонеты как-то мимо себя пропустила. Вы тогда быстро переводили, что-то в них не показалось или тема не заинтересовала, но я устремилась к сонету 12, все внимание к нему.  А потом 14, 15, все мои любимые)

А вот Маршак): В любви и в слове - правда мой закон,
И я пишу, что милая прекрасна,
Как все, кто смертной матерью рожден,
А не как солнце или месяц ясный. - соннет про то, что он не пишет, что прекрасна) и вообще не про любимую) Маршак такой выдумщик. Это про 21.

Да, смешно)   Они все пишут, кто во что горазд. Меня еще покритикуйте: Но ты поверь словам любви моей, Которая  от  сердца рождена, Она  прекрасна истиной своей, Хоть в золотом сиянье не видна.

@Sharon надо ли?) не хочу)

А я не обижусь) я не настоящий поэт) Мне просто  эти "роды"  не понравились, и я их решила вовсе убрать)

Не знаю, мне просто кажется концовка строфы ну очень сильная: "но не такая яркая/светлая,
Как золото свеч, что держат небесный свод." Как можно это упускать, а даже Чайковский навыдумывал ерунды.

Мне просто эти "роды" не понравились - ну я сделал "материнство", очень мягкое слово, роды конечно грубо) Ну и не говоря о том, что там никто конечно не заметил ритмической сбивки в третьей строфе с переменой настроения. А она там ну просто отличная. Там же запятые стоят.

Я отстаиваю свою идею: рожденная сердцем любовь)

рожденная сердцем любовь) - нет это хорошо(хотя немножечко банально), а вот следующие две строчки чисто выдуманные, а у Ш там несколько поворотов, понимаете. Он не пишет линейно, он говорит пол фразы, а потом делает резкий разворот смысла.

my love is as fair
As any mother's child, though not so bright
As those gold candles fix'd in heaven's air:

Моя любовь чиста как каждой рождённый матерью,  хотя не такая светлая, как те золотые свечи удерживающие небесный свод.

А я перевожу: золотые свечи, закрепленные на небесном своде.

ну может и так) может я выдумываю)

Мне всё у вас нравится)  Почему-то.

Ну я старался) мне показалось, что это очень не банально, что горящие свечи удерживают небо) , то есть как титаны греков, только свечи, которые ставят люди) Про этикет тоже хорошо вставилось, вроде все отлично. немножечко выбивается все равно это фраза почестями в чести, не знаю почему, а может кажется. Но хотелось что-то такое вставить, потому что там тоже Фер ... фер - какая-то игра слов.

Да, классно, красивый образ. Вы действительно поэт,  ну я так думаю. // Трудная раза: And every fair with his fair doth rehearse,  Я ее даже дословно не очень понимаю.

у вас ошибка, что вы his перевели как "твой", то есть вы попали в обаяние шаблона, что вроде стихи о друге. А стих о неком другом поэте или поэтах, о "нём". Ну и вообще, я так думаю это чисто цикл Чёрной дамы.

Насчет цикла у меня сомнения. Я не против, если ему нравится прекрасный друг.  Частная жизнь)

Я не против, если ему нравится прекрасный друг. Частная жизнь)- да не было никакого прекрасного друга или чернокожей подруги. Речь о другой любви, хотя часть стихов посвящённых женщинам вроде про страсть тоже. 141, остальные не знаю.

Откуда нам это знать,  о его жизни ничего неизвестно. Вот взялся гений из ниоткуда и ушел в никуда.  Все личные данные будто уничтожены кем, даже театр сгорел.  // Сонет 144 На радость и печаль,
по воле рока,
Два друга, две любви владеют мной:
Мужчина светлокудрый, светлоокий
И женщина, в чьих взорах мрак ночной. // Что это за образы?  Аллегории?

@Sharon - конечно:The better angel is a man right fair;
The worser spirit a woman coloured ill.

Выкиньте Маршака уже) все, Маршак остался в качестве "он" в 21 соннете.

Переведите  сонет 144, тогда выкину)

Лучший ангел нравственный мужчина, худший дух женщина окрашенная недомоганием. Что олицетворяет женщина и мужчина - сложно сказать, но точно не "светлоокий мужчина и черноокая женщина". Тут аллегория и на Адама с Евой, и на много чего, женскую и мужскую натуру.

Шекспир в чем суть, не называет напрямую ничего конкретного, он даже бога богом не называет: золотые свечи в небесах... пожалуйста. Он не идет по пути именования и понятий, он идет по пути описания и образности.

Я бы послушала вас в переводе и в трактовке) Интересно! Настоящая философия.

В общем, я придумал такую вещь: называет смысловое среднее. Суть не в том, чтобы назвать что-то словом, а в том чтобы дать описание причины А' и следствия взаимодействия с А'', тогда получается зафиксированный  А находится между двумя описаниями. Вот Ш примерно так делает, это не аристотелевский подход. когда сплошь терминология и ни одного описания. Тут наоборот, сплошь описания и почти нет никаких имён. Грубо говоря, Ш играет в игру: угадай, о чём я, если это: черное, женское, жестокое... и тп.

А Аристотеля все через значения и логику, а здесь не значения а связки: в эту сторону одной, а немного поменять, всё совсем наоборот - как так? Ш не даёт почти ни одной оценки, оценки все очень двойственные. Я даже 17 в этом плане плохо перевёл, потому что стих протух), но пока не знаю как уйти от оценки.

А как же персонификация,  если никаких имен, а только описания.  П.  в мифологии,  И образность тоже свойственно мифологии. Разве это не ваше понимание при описании мира.  Ш. пишет про друга, а мы должны видеть смысловое среднее?  А зачем нужна такая поэзия.  Людям нужен эмоциональный опыт,   взятый их жизни.

В мифологии тоже с персонификацией не всегда чётко. А тут он пишет как раз не про персону, а про то, что в каком-то я читал 40 или 50 каком-то, что в каждом по одной тени, в Адонисе например, а в друге в его сонм теней. Вы же Аристотеля не хотите читать, а он там пишет, что произведение, хоть и имеет героя, но суть героя, что это некий собирательный образ из рассказов о персонаже, может даже реально существовавшем, но затем, его имя начинает обрастать историями, и получается, что это не конкретный человек, а кто-то наделённый различными образами, коллективный образ чего-то или кого-то

Если поэт не испытал живого чувства, я не доверяю его поэзии, и даже Аристотель здесь не поможет.

Я понял, что конечно, стих можно посвятить кому-то, но на самом деле, речь об образе, человек воспринимает всё через призму отражений, то есть там все равно будет смесь, и можно потом и стих дописывать и доделывать, достраивая. Как делал Ш? возможно он исходил из некой посылки, например садовника 1-12, но затем, он стал применять эти идеи к разным людям, которые были для него важны и любимы, чтобы найти субстанцию любви, как алхимики искали философский камень... А затем и от принципов начальных стал отходить, сосредоточусь только на любви и красоте, неких качествах или некой энергии

Он испытывал, но он это чувство обрабатывал, а не выражал просто через набор эмоциональных штампов, он выделял субстанцию любви и субстанцию красоты. Без ассоциаций со стандартами. Я вам пришлю песню, покажу, что я имею ввиду)

Ш. только мыслитель? Создавал эмоции из посылок? А сам не пережил ни страсти,ни ревности, ни страданий. Как-то не верится. Но вы меня простите, пожалуйста, за недоверие) Для меня эмоции много значат. Просто само творчество подразумевает определенное эмоциональное состояние автора, то есть вдохновение. А обобщение всегда присутствует в литературе.

Ш. только мыслитель? - нене, мыслитель, это какой-то дед, Ш скорее всего просто записал часть его мыслей в соннетах 1-12, возможно это вообще его наставник был, алхимик какой-то. А Ш., он жил, но творчески, так как его наставил алхимик, пытаясь ТЫ-любовью прорасти в людях. Ш начинается с 13 соннета, а до этого это не его мысли. Там общие принципы какие-то и тп. А вот с 13-14 начинается Я.

Вот 21 соннет, какая проблема? ЕГО стихи не привлекают кого-то, вот он пишет. А в 1-12 там наставления - живи так. живи сяк, не про самого автора речь, про самого только в 12 есть немножко эмоции, как прощание: я мол, устал, я ухожу). А Ш он конечно и мыслитель, и поэт, все вместе. "он" в 21 соннете может вообще Петрарка какой-нибудь. И даже Виона читаешь, там больше от Я и себя, чем у Ш, у Ш только когда он совсем жалуется как в 66 бывает Я его. А в других это и Я и игра, игра слов,  игра образом и какие-то скрытые смыслы - средние. И ещё Ш бард, а не просто поэт, у него именно песни.

А у поэтов часто словесная жвачка бывает, какая-нибудь бессмыслица, но звучащая прикольно. У Ш не так. У него слова имеют смысл и живут внутри повествования.

И я в письмо наверное лучше напишу, про технику Ш.

Спасибо вам за перевод сонета 22, чуть позже напишу о впечатлении.  И Шекспира еще пытаюсь прочитать)  // Некоторые строфы мне очень нравятся по форме, но я общую картину еще не вполне вижу. // Есть вопрос по самой первой строке, запятые не ясны.   Переводчик дает: Мое зеркало не убедит меня, что я стар.  Это правильный смысл?

@Sharon переводы существующие не отражают суть, не чувствуют, нужно читать в контексте других соннетов, я спою будет ясно, там прекрасно всё. Всё моё!) так говорит старик.

Скорее всего да)  И с нетерпением жду исполнения)  // Но вы про запятые всё же скажите, они правильно стоят? В таких текстах с инверсиями смысл от знаков во многом зависит.

@Sharon вы же знаете миф о хроносе? Да, запятые все на месте, это ответ.

Противоречивый миф.  Он кушал своих детей, а зачем?  Ответы у всех разные.   // А переводчик дает неправильную информацию по первой строке?  Меня эта  строка совсем запутала: (1) да, стар; нет, не стар. Извините мою непонятливость)

@Sharon  а он говорит, что не пожирал, а хранил, как мать) берёг память) не слышите? Ну он объясняет, почему он не старее человека, который называет его стариком. Человек спорит со временем. Но отдаёт тебя ему, а он хранит. Хронос-хранит.

И ещё я подумал, что тот огонь который воровал прометей, это тоже связано со временем и бессмертием, дар времени, вечный огонь. У зевса воровал, зевс как узурпатор огня. Вообще это какая-то эпическая трагедия, как ненаписанная пьеса. Короче время говорит, что всё здесь моё. И ты и твоё сердце и стекло.

Спасибо! Очень интересно!  Правда, в моем сознании  это звучит как эпический детектив))  Ну просто потому что действительно интересно)

@Sharon ага) пусть детектив, эпический детектив)

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/71XZjZa_BTxhwQ -22

История такая, зевс и команда, с прометеем убивают старика, но перед тем как уйти время обращается к прометею. Прометей вылепил людей из глины, но люди страдали, и прометей украл огонь и даровал людям огонь, которым зажёг сердца смертных, возможно, отдал им своё сердце, в котором унёс огонь, за что зевс его наказал, последняя строчка пророчество юному прометею.

Впечатление…  Я будто случайно попала в театр времен Шекспира. Зал замер в молчании, все напряженно слушают. Я понимаю, что на сцене разыгрывается трагедия,  актеры  талантливы, а пьеса прекрасна. Мне реально страшно,  но смысла слов я не понимаю.  // Мы плохо знаем мифологию, проходили когда-то в школе, а для этих людей олимпийские боги и титаны вполне реальны.  К тому же я не знаю  самых общих фактов о мифах.  Несмотря на то, что Хроноса  отождествляли с Титаном Кроносом, он был гораздо старше и могущественнее Кроноса.

Он является персонификацией хаоса природного времени и отождествляется с хронологическим потоком. А Кронос — это древнегреческий титан, который был отцом Зевса и правил во время золотого века. Детей своих пожирал Кронос,  но как греки воспринимали этот факт по отношению к смертным людям?  Как это выразил Шекспир в своих сонетах? // Матрица Шекспира  (о представителях нашей малограмотной эпохи):  «Меня иногда упрекали в недостаточной учености, но видели бы они вас...»  В общем,  всё грустно, но поправимо)  Спасибо автору за прекрасное исполнение.

Спасибо за перевод. Я сначала тоже пропустила сонет 13, а сейчас попробовала его перевести по переводчику. Если я правильно поняла содержание,  то прочитала там нечто совершенно новое для себя. Сравнила с вашим переводом.  Там есть о чем поговорить. Если вы не против, то я бы открыла новую тему  для сонета 13 со своим очень общим и  коротким ответом. Вы могли бы принять участие в обсуждении или просто высказать  какое-либо понимание?

@Sharon да, наверное, получился вообще самый сложный на сегодня соннет. пытаюсь исполнить, пока не могу все удержать)

Спасибо! Не удивляйтесь форме вопроса, можно  рассказать о худ. форме) Я позже добавлю второй ответ с разбором текста по переводчику (как я его поняла).

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/CN5MW1g7F-iaUQ - 13. послушайте, может у вас отпадёт часть вопросов) это спор между учениками и учителем, стариком.

Классно! Очень впечатляет? Мне действительно понравилось. Будто я ваш ученик, который слушает учителя.  Его авторитет и так высок, но также убедительны слова, личное присутствие  и магия голоса)  Спасибо за искренние эмоции. // Но как быть с читателями,  поймут ли) Вопросы у меня все же остались...

Спасибо! Это сонет 24, но вы его не пописали! И мой первый взгляд: какое хорошее стихО (почему-то придумалось это слово), но почему же  я его не знаю. Потом разобралась.  / Почему хорошее?  Это красота чистой формы, хотя некоторые погрешности я вижу. Форма (ритмический рисунок и гармония слов)  может восприниматься и без понимания смысла, потому что сама имеет эстетическую ценность. / Но все же в чем смысл? Сложный сонет, Переводчик предлагает что-то смутное, его самого надо переводить, аналогично Маршак.

Художник влюблен и поэтому пристрастен, портрет не будет объективным? Или напротив, именно в этом случае можно увидеть истинную красоту человека? Художник видит в глазах солнце и рисует свое солнечное восприятие, хотя вот сердечных тайн любимой все же не видит. / Неясна вторая строфа. Переводчик: Ибо через художника вы должны видеть его мастерство, Чтобы узнать, где находится твое истинное изображение, Которое до сих пор висит в лавке у меня на груди , ЧЬИ ОКНА ЗАСТЕКЛЕНЫ ТВОИМИ ГЛАЗАМИ.  Ваш: И сохнет он уж в сердца мастерской, ТОТ В ЧЕЙ ХРУСТАЛЬНЫЙ ГЛАЗ СВЕТ НЕ ПРОНИК. В чем смысл образа?

shop - это мастерская.) окно от ОКО, глаз - это орган, а око, окно в сердце, перегородка между внутренним миром и внешним. Глаз - это художник,он отражает мир, он различает свет и тьму, но не видит то, что находится за ним, внутри, то, что смотрим на мир. Люди смотрят на работы художника тоже глазами, не всегда внутренним взором.

Я спою будет понятнее. Он создает человека, рисуя его черты по своему подобию и вкладывая в него огонь.

Спасибо, интересно! Все-таки  читателям надо еще много работать на правильным восприятием Шекспира.)  А кто из переводчиков ближе всего понял смысл?

Мне кажется, все заблудились.

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Hq6ud92TLs8JbQ - 24

Восторг, да!  Музыка раскачивает эмоции, на музыку ложатся слова и звучат как единое целое. И смена голоса (это вообще чудо!) добавляет впечатлений. Не весь смысл я еще понимаю, но знаю,  правда — это то, что прекрасно! И желаю дальнейших успехов в творчестве нашему дорогому поэту. Или барду?

@Sharon не знаю, просто читаю Ш, учусь и иногда продолжаю музыку и мысли.

@Sharon Shake Spear - мне тут сказали, колебать и пронзать.

ВЕЗДЕ ТАЙНЫ. Фамилия отца была Shakspere (Shak = трясти и spere = острие, копье). Шекспир в полученном двор. гербе  обыгрывает именно этот образ: сокол, зажавший в лапе копье). Однако зачем-то в ранних изданиях  он пишет фамилию через дефис и в другой транскрипции Shake-speare. Может быть, это своего рода псевдоним? Но в посмертном издании дефис почему-то исчез, а измененная  транскрипция осталась, хотя, вроде бы уже все знали кто автор этих пьес. Причем в подписях он придерживается родового варианта. В церк. записях о рождении и смерти – тоже родовой вариант. https://proza.ru/2011/11/13/1230

Спасибо!  Кажется, наш Шекспир влюблен, но чем-то озабочен)  Гордость, слава и т.д. Стих мне кажется безупречным, с формой все в порядке) Хочется еще добавить музыки.)  // Не очень ясна вторая строфа. Я собиралась понять так. Любимцы славны, пока  угодны покровителям, Но гордые вельможи лишат их благосклонности, если они в чем-то не угодят  своему покровителю. (Значит, надо  тешить и угождать.)

У Маршака своя модель:  счастливчик нежится, пока на него светит благосклонное солнце, но слава уйдет вместе с благосклонностью. Гордость у него куда-то пропала. // Переводчик дает что-то неопределенное.
Фавориты великих князей распускают свои прекрасные листья
Но,  как ноготки в солнечном оке,
И в них самих похоронена их гордость,
Ибо, нахмурившись, они умирают во всей своей славе.//
Но кто все же гордый и в чем гордость?  Извините мою непонятливость)

@Sharon мне кажется в этом и Ш, чтобы запихнуть 2 смысла в одну строчки и каждый из них одинаково плох, ведёт к одному концу, такая комедия)

А мы вроде бы считаем неоднозначность погрешностью стилистики (это начиная с 17 века, в Новое время)).  Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее смысл золотого цветка. Этот образ центральный и очень красивый, хочется его понять по возможности эмоционально)

@Sharon - мериголд - счастливый в золоте, название календулы, но я думаю златоцвет не сильно рознится, то есть цветок похожий на солнце, но солнцем не являющийся. Календула или Златоцвет (англ. Marigold). https://disk.yandex.ru/d/P3gdvBXZljz0Xg -25

Спасибо! Все чудесно! Мне очень нравится ваш волшебный театр.  Для меня он именно такой.  // Мы счастливы в солнце, все краски меркнут. когда его нет.  От жизни и любви мы ждем такого же сияния. Ошибка человечества? Но, возможно, у Шекспира другой смысл...

@Sharon у Ш чернота же)

Я помню –  блеклый, блестящий чёрный, светящийся чёрный. Но это слишком глубокий для меня уровень понимания Шекспира)

@Sharon звездное небо над головой Канта тоже похоже. Хотя перевёрнуто. у Ш звёздное небо внутри, а над головой моральный закон, солнечный. black дословно блеклый, но у нас звучит как белый). И, кстати говоря "белолика, черноброва, нрава кроткого такого..." - как вам?(вот отчего её бровь воронёна... therefore my mistress brows are raven black)

Не знаю, у меня мало эрудиции,  а Канта я по песне изучала) https://yandex.ru/video/preview/6776157225705218996  Белолика, черноброва мне нравится, тоже думала, почему так, что за каноны красоты.

Бровь это вроде чело, чёрный разум, неограниченный. Неограниченный умом и стереотипами. А белолика - нравственна. Ну и кротка, скромна.

@Sharon да я тоже только пару фраз из Канта знаю) но теперь хоть песню послушал)

Спасибо вам за перевод и за все ваши труды! Чем дольше я нахожусь в теме, тем больше убеждаюсь в том,  что истинного Шекспира  мы пока не знаем. У Маршака очень хорошие стихи по близкой теме, но все-таки это не Великий Бард. Он как бы пересказывает Ш.,  но своими словами, так что иногда неточен смысл, а многие образы вовсе не раскрыты. Так и в сонете 27 у меня есть к нему вопросы. Мне бы хотелось остановиться на таком моменте. В большинстве случаев  в каждом сонете есть центральная деталь, то есть самый яркий образ, к которому стремится весь его рассказ - это как вишенка на торте.

Здесь это драгоценный камень, освещающий черную ночь. У Маршака его нет совсем, а у вас жемчуг, что много лучше и конкретнее, чем просто камень. Но по этой строке у меня вопрос, там как смысл не очень ясен. Хотелось бы убрать скобки (в стихах они вообще не очень желательны), и я эту строку слышу так: Как жемчуга,  висящие в ночИ, Чей дряхлый лик они омолодят. Извините мою смелость)  И очень хочется услышать музыкальный вариант.

@Sharon в оригинале скобки, вот пытаюсь сохранить. в 3 строфе отсылка к "глаза так ловко прячут в свой ларец" - вот он прячет в глазах  дорогие образы, и тем самым удерживает мрак или ужас внутри него, как звёзды удерживают мрак/ужас чёрного ночного неба. А вообще, стих про сон или сны, но наверное то как сейчас можно говорить "осознанные" сны. То есть подход к сну, как к важной части человеческого бытия и духовной жизни.

@Sharon поэтика Ш похожа на математику. Он вводит образы последовательно, а далее начинает к ним обращаться снова. Форма образа может меняться. Может меняться несколько имя сущности: время, жнец, смерть, ночной мрак и тп.(поэтому в 128 речь не про фортепиано, а про смерть и осень harvest reap - осенняя жатва - RIP, так оно произносится, пишут на могилах, это латынь, rest in peace по-английски.) То есть важно и изменение и звучание. Причём звучание может вступать во взаимодействие с написанием. Это тоже забавно.

"Лишь я и мысль (как долго я терплю),
В желаньи истом сблизиться с тобой," - это читается двойственно, если произносить или только читать. Маршак же, с самого начала неточен в образности и с каждым стихом теряет оригинальную образность заменяя своими бедными шаблонами про любовь к другу и подобное, поэтому ему приходится из раза в раз повторять одно и тоже, потому что он уже вообще не понимает, что вообще происходит. Финкель слишком груб, чтобы понять изящество и иронию. Чайковский хотя и религиозен, но простоват, у него нет глубины, ну и иронии нет. Иронии вообще ни у кого нет.

Тоже с подстрочником, в нём нет иронии, все сухо изложено, сейчас вот сколько я смотрел переводы, все переводят именно по подстрочнику, поэтому у всех одно и тоже выходит. Однообразное сухое сено, вместо чувственного пира наедине. Игра слов и образов, есть только в оригинале, в подстрочнике её уже нет и музыки нет.

И что теперь с этим делать? Тогда Шекспиру нужны  хорошие переводы и пояснения к ним.  // Вы объяснили 3-ю строфу, и стало понятно.  У вас как бы жемчуг держит ночь, а переводчик дает:  …как драгоценный камень, подвешенный  в жуткой ночи, (hung in ghastly night). // А вместо скобок можно запятые поставить?//   И еще вопрос по 4-й строке, у вас 12 стоп, разве нельзя записать 10 стоп:  Лик ночи дряхлой, крася, молодят.  //   Может, правда Ш. пишет про сны?  Но как читателю догадаться об этом?  Нельзя на это как-то намекнуть?)

Ш. вообще выглядит в моих глазах всё больше как философ, а все видят однообразную любовную лирику. Я уже подозреваю, что он был герметиком, были у них тогда философские кружки)   Герметизм — это учение о высших законах природы, подчиняющейся как принципу причинности, так и принципу аналогии. Вам, кажется, больше нравится аналогия)

" подвешенный в жуткой ночи, (hung in ghastly night). // А вместо скобок можно запятые поставить?// И еще вопрос по 4-й строке, у вас 12 стоп, разве нельзя записать 10 стоп: Лик ночи дряхлой, крася, молодят" - да, надо пофиксить 4 строчку и третья не совсем правильная, там "висящие в призрачной ночи" дословно, то есть это или висящие или повешенные .

hung: past-participle adjective from hang (v.)

"Ш. вообще выглядит в моих глазах всё больше как философ, а все видят однообразную любовную лирику" - это как про Платона говорить, что он эротоман. Хотя сейчас когда говоришь платоническая любовь, многие сразу думают почему-то про эротику, то есть совершенно путают. Возможно герметизм. И связанная с этим герменевтика замешанная на толковании текстов, отсюда и двойственность смыслов.

@Sharon "сочетало элементы популярной древнегреческой философии, халдейской астрологии, персидской магии и древнеегипетской, позже греческой и арабской, алхимии. Герметизм оказал влияние на такие направления эзотеризма как сабеизм, мандеизм, суфизм, розенкрейцерство, масонство, мартинизм, оккультизм, теософия, традиционализм, некоторые направления нью-эйдж, а также на кеметизм и др." - очень похоже на то, то есть это вся эта ветвь алхимии, масонства и прочего+ греки.

Все эти розы и кресты понятно становится откуда ноги растут.

А можно обособленную краткую форму: Как жемчуга, повешены в ночи,...

@Sharon я нашёл слово сочетающее подвешенность и призрачность, ушёл правда фальшивый испуг, но так ведь лучше?

@Sharon я не знаю, почему у меня выходит совершенно иначе, чем у других перекладчиков) почему?) всё наоборот.

Это всё второй закон бытия Трисмегиста (принцип соответствия/аналогии): Мир есть то, что вы желаете в нём увидеть.

Спасибо! Прекрасный перевод, мне все нравится. Но есть вопросы по форме. Можно так написать: (1) Кляну И жребий мой и свой удел, (2)  Вдруг вспомню о тебе, и снова лад,
(Как жаворонка трель с земли встречает // рассвет*) пою  гимн у небесных врат. / sings hymns at heaven's gate;  // Чувства лирического героя понятны, но что их причина? И кто он, простолюдин, завидующий сильным мира сего, или аристократ, гонимый судьбой. Сам Шекспир всегда в маске)

@Sharon жеребий допустимое написание) я посмотрел, запятая лишняя, да, и скобок в оригинале нет, это на сайте че-то они есть, без них даже лучше. "а жеребий, или жребий, участок, доля, пай, доставшийся в надел по жеребью, или вообще
рок, судьба, участь, доля, счастье. Даль" Про Ш напишу на почту.

Классный получился стих! Совсем немного изменений, я чувства выражены ярче, понятнее, вызывают сочувствие)  Интересно, почему так?) // У меня остался вопрос  по этой строке: "Его иметь привязанностей круг".  Его – это про кого?

@Sharon кого-то, это стих про то, что человек колеблется и хочет влезть в чужую шкуру, притвориться другим, полагая, что там лучше где нас нет, выбирает/создаёт себе кумиров, которым пытается подражать, соответствуя образам их успешности и тп. Там просто слово такое possessed которое трактуется как быть зависимым или подчиняться (дьяволу в оригинале), но тут некой группе приятелей. человек зависимый от привязанностей к другим, которые его используют для своих целей, мне кажется что-то такое.


Дословный перевод имеет примерно такой смысл:

Но почему тебе не объявить войну времени, этому кровавому тирану, и не укрепить свой упадок более действенными способами, чем мой стих?
Теперь ты на вершине счастливых часов, и много еще девственных садов, которые принесли бы тебе живые цветы, которые лучше твоей раскрашенной подделки.
Так и линии жизни  сама жизнь восстанавливает, как карандаш времени или моя ученическая ручка.  По внутренней ценности и внешней справедливости ты можешь жить самостоятельно в глазах людей.
Отдавая себя, ты сохраняешь постоянство,  и ты должен жить, влекомый своим собственным милым мастерством.

Идею бессмертия я считаю основной в сонетах Шекспира, но она каждый раз дана особенным образом.  Кажется, что речь идет ни много ни мало, как о каких-то «технологиях», но понять их не так просто. Я полагаю, что какое-то духовное начало в себе человек может передать потомкам и сохранить во времени.

А что именно можно считать достаточно ценным для хранения? Информационное поле земли бесконечно, но как сохранить в нем свою индивидуальность, чтобы не быть забытым. А если говорить языком эзотерики, то попросту раскодированным.
Конечно, не стоит столь прямолинейно рассуждать о подобных вещах — мне кажется, метафоричность нашего сознания ближе к истине, чем подобные теории. Но тем важнее передать философию Шекспира в художественных образах, приблизившись по возможности к образному языку автора сонетов.
Так или иначе, но вот Шекспир всегда с нами, присутствует в нашей жизни, и это бесспорно)
Уильям Шекспир (William Shakespeare). Сонет 16.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о сонете 18)
Сонеты 16 и 18 близки по теме, хотя содержание стихов раскрывается в разных образах. Но все же философия их сложна для понимания. В обоих случаях можно определить ту фразу, в которой содержится основной смысл: ...Смерть не закроет тебя своей тенью, пока ты растешь  в вечном соответствии со временем. Nor shall death brag thou wand'rest in his shade, When in eternal lines to time thou grow'st.
Понимание сказанного  сложно укладывается в сознание: как индивидуальный рост и соответствие со своим временем для человека сохранит его присутствие в жизни людей, живущих после него?
Но ведь это метафора! Может, и не надо ее понимать, а следует на этом остановиться, так как  наши возможности познания в этом мире весьма ограниченны.
Опыт перевода сонета в прозе:
Сравнить ли тебя с летним днем? Но ты более прекрасен и более постоянен, чем лето. Бурные ветры треплют милые майские бутоны, а срок летнего отпуска слишком короткий.
Иногда очень ярко сияет солнце, но часто тускнеет его золотой свет. И каждый раз сияющая красота приходит в упадок, случайно или намеренно природа меняет свой курс.
Но твое вечное лето не угаснет, и ты не утратишь своей красоты, которой владеешь, и  Смерть не закроет тебя своей тенью, — пока ты растешь  в вечном соответствии со временем.
Пока люди могут дышать, а их глаза могут видеть...
Пока это так,  это дает жизнь тебе.

О воплощении художественной идеи при переводе
Написать хорошее стихотворение непросто,  и даже у самых известных поэтов не все стихи удачны. Но перевести стихотворение с другого языка еще сложнее, особенно если это староанглийский язык 16 века. Надо правильно понять смысл, нельзя далеко уходить от авторского текста.
И тогда начинаешь копировать по возможности лексику (ключевые слова) и фразеологию оригинала,  хотя и собственный текст приходится все же добавлять. Теперь все, стих получился?
Да ничуть, потому что поэзия — это язык образов, а образ у автора не спишешь. Здесь и начинается настоящее творчество, ведь получится или не получится — никогда не знаешь.  Но вот копирование текста может помешать при переводе.
Вроде бы результат неплохой, стих гладкий,  правильный и даже красивый, все на месте, но это не Шекспир, не его душа.  Это собственное стихотворение на тему английского поэта. Это я вижу  по переводу Маршака и по своему собственному переводу.
А что вы думаете по поводу работы нашего  автора — насколько верно понята основная идея и как она отражена  в предложенном им переводе сонета 16?  Самой сложной  оказалась третья строфа и концовка.
P. S. Собственно говоря, дело даже не в переводе конкретного стихотворения, а  вообще в сонетах Шекспира. После переводов Маршака в 1949 году многие были увлечены  поэзией английского барда, но насколько актуально его творчество сейчас? Обычно люди знают несколько широко известных сонетов, в которых выражены яркие чувства, понятные им. Но первый и самый значительный по объему цикл мало кому известен именно потому, что его художественная идея остается неосознанной.
Не понято то, что это рассуждения поэта о смысле жизни каждого человека, которые он дает в разных образах, а вовсе не нравоучения молодому человеку с единственным выводом.
Точно такая же история была во времена Шекспира, когда студенчество и все образованные люди восхищалось его работами, а потом вдруг надолго забыли. Ушли из жизни те современники поэта, которые хорошо знали и понимали его творчество.
Хотелось бы, чтобы такое понимание состоялось и сейчас, когда людям особенно нужна нравственная опора.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ от 14.09.2024
О «брачных» сонетах Шекспира (сонеты 1 — 17)
БЕЛОКУРЫЙ АДОНИС В БРАЧНЫХ СОНЕТАХ ШЕКСПИРА
Пусть другие хвалят Спенсера ц Чосера, я же буду 
поклоняться сладостному мистеру Шекспиру и, чтобы 
почтить его, буду класть "Венеру и Адониса" под
свою подушку..."  (из студенческой  пьесы 1599 
года).

О БРАЧНЫХ СОНЕТАХ
Сетевые рассказы о мистере Шекспире иногда  поражают изысканностью фантазий их авторов. Если дать таким материалам общую оценку, то это сведение жизни и творчества гениального поэта к поверхностным  рассуждениям и плоским картинкам, причем  и в том и другом. А вот о художественном пространстве и многозначности образов мало кто рассуждает. С другой стороны, возможно, лет  через триста-четыреста потомки тоже увидят в «Евгении Онегине» заурядный бытовой сюжет.
Первые 17 сонетов названы «брачными», и уж пожалуйста не сомневайтесь в этом, так как специалисты точно всё установили.  В них Шекспир убеждает своего молодого друга (скорее всего Генри Ризли графа Саутгемтона) непременно жениться, чтобы продолжить род. Зачем? Конечно же для того, чтобы сохранить в потомстве свою невероятную красоту, пока не увяла.
ПОЭМА "ВЕНЕРА И АДОНИС"
В 1693 году Шекспир посвящает двадцатилетнему графу поэму «Венера и Адонис», тогда же, вероятно, он пишет цикл брачных сонетов. Посвящение, кстати, было очень сердечным для актера, который обращается к аристократу, то есть без требуемой почтительности. Но, может быть, они были друзьями, что тоже не совсем обычно. Или же Шекспир все же не был просто актером?
Но ведь в поэме Шекспира Адонис отвергает Венеру и продолжать свой род отказывается.  "Чувственность в её речах бьет через край, тело богини прямо-таки трепещет от желания. (Ее увещевания о продолжении рода, обращенные к юноше, как две капли воды напоминают увещевания героя сонетов к белокурому другу.) Доводы ее красноречивы и убедительны, и Адонис уже готов сдаться. И все же разум в нем побеждает, и юноше удается устоять под натиском чувств" (Владимир Косулин. Тайнопись Шекспира.)
А потом Адонис погибает на охоте от клыков вепря. Вся поляна была залита кровью, жуткое зрелище! И безутешная богиня превращает кровь юноши в красно-белый цветок анемон. В чем здесь-то смысл? Параллель в содержании очевидна, так что какое-то объяснение желательно. Может быть, истинное бессмертие поэт понимает как-то иначе?
ГЕНРИ РИЗЛИ 3-Й ГРАФ САУТГЕМПТОН
Кстати, в действительности дело было не столько в красоте белокурого друга (красота только предлог), сколько в необходимости. Тогда браки в аристократических семействах заключали именно так, и невеста была найдена, но непутевый сынок всячески увиливал от брачных уз. Говорят даже, что матушка заказала Шекспиру десяток-другой сонетов, чтобы уговорить сына.
Но отпрыск оказался строптивым, невесту себе нашел сам, к тому же совсем неподходящую для его статуса. Расстроил всю семью и даже королеву, просто политический скандал! И вообще, граф был хоть и прекрасен, но мужских черт характера ему  тоже было не занимать.
«Генри Ризли по натуре был бойцом, и кровь у него была горячая. На его счету (помимо декоративных, но все-таки турниров) значились дуэли и прочие разборки с неумеренным рукоприкладством, в которые он ввязывался очертя голову, невзирая на присутствие коронованных особ, не зная ни страха, ни подобострастия. От жизни он, видимо, старался взять все, не слишком заморачиваясь по поводу морали». Их статьи  https://proza.ru/2023/04/25/1597
Кстати, умер Генри Ризли в 1624 году от морового поветрия в военном лагере в Нидерландах (тогда шла война с Испанией), причем одновременно со своим сыном, и на этом род графов пресекся в 4-м поколении. Такая вот грустная насмешка судьбы над всем родом человеческим.
ПОРТРЕТ ШЕКСПИРА (из семьи Коббе)
Но есть еще один удивительный факт.  В 2006 году в коллекции англо-ирландской семьи Коббе был обнаружен портрет, который сейчас считается единственным прижизненным портретом Шекспира, хотя подписи на нем нет. "Портрет размером 38 на 54 сантиметра был выполнен неизвестным художником примерно в 1610 году, за 6 лет до смерти великого драматурга. Вероятнее всего, портрет был создан по заказу 3-го графа Саутгемптонского, который был близким другом и покровителем Шекспира. Портрет хранился в семейной коллекции, передаваясь из поколение в поколение". https://hojja-nusreddin.livejournal.com/1974084.html
На этом портрете Шекспир изумительно хорош: тонкие аристократические черты, яркая красота — и взгляд, устремленный на будущие поколения через века. Вот кто уж действительно прекрасен.
ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
Ну а в брачных сонетах каждый переводчик видит что-то свое, но некоторые, как мне кажется, видят такие откровения,  что приходится только удивляться. А уж художественного пространства они не видят точно.
Поэзия – это  не информационный текст, а  осмысление действительности в художественных образах. Именно это прежде всего надо видеть в сонетах Шекспира, и такое восприятие всегда индивидуально. А переводчику сложнее вдвойне – ведь всё  понятое и пережитое  надо выразить  в собственном стихе, и тоже не как обычную информацию.
И тогда удивительным кажется желание «специалистов по Шекспиру»  считать наследие Великого Барда своей темой, а остальных относить к «околошекспирью». Мне думается, что жизнь сама все расставит по местам без их участия.
https://w-shakespeare.ru/library/shekspir-zhizn-i-deyatelnost-ego-sovremennie-emu-literatura-i-kulturniy-stroy8.html
